# System.Drawing.Common.Bitmap cross platform alternatives

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, imagesharp

I am looking to convert PDF files into images. [Docnet](https://github.com/GowenGit/docnet) is able to convert the pdf into `bytes[]` and their samples show how to save this `byte[]` into an image file using `Bitmap`. [Documentation](https://github.com/GowenGit/docnet/blob/master/examples/nuget-usage/NugetUsageAnyCpu/PdfToImageExamples.cs)

However, the solution won't work on linux machine since `Bitmap` requires few libraries pre-installed on the system.

I've tried ImageSharp to convert the `byte[]` using `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load<Bgra32>(rawBytes)`, however, it throws `Unhandled exception. SixLabors.ImageSharp.InvalidImageContentException: PNG Image does not contain a data chunk`.

Does anyone knows any alternative to achieve this.

PS - I'm open to explore any other cross platform FREE supported alternatives to convert PDF files to images.

Comment: If a Png doesn't contain an IDAT chunk it's not valid. You're obviously doing something horribly wrong and not passing the correct data. http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html

Comment: Yes, `Docnet` has an API that gets you the raw bytes of the image from a pdf document. Documentation mentions that it is in GBRA format. I'm not sure how do I convert this raw bytes so that `ImageSharp` be able to load this.

Comment: You want `LoadPixelData<TPixel>`. See the API docs.

https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_LoadPixelData__1___0___System_Int32_System_Int32_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine with ImageSharp assuming  Docnet works then ImageSharp will work fine for you.

The trick is you want to be using the `Image.LoadPixelData<Bgra32>(rawBytes, width, height);` API not the `Image.Load<Bgra32>(encodedBytes);` one.

```cs
using Docnet.Core;
using Docnet.Core.Models;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;

using var docReader = DocLib.Instance.GetDocReader(
           "wikipedia_0.pdf",
           new PageDimensions(1080, 1920));

using var pageReader = docReader.GetPageReader(0);

var rawBytes = pageReader.GetImage();

var width = pageReader.GetPageWidth();
var height = pageReader.GetPageHeight();

// this is the important line, here you are taking a byte array that 
// represents the pixels directly where as Image.Load<Bgra32>()
// is expected an encoded image in png, jpeg etc format
using var img = Image.LoadPixelData<Bgra32>(rawBytes, width, height);
// you are likely going to want this as well otherwise you might end up with transparent parts.
img.Mutate(x => x.BackgroundColor(Color.White));

img.Save("wikipedia_0.png");
```

Comment: Thank you so much @tocsoft. I've been struggling to solve this for quite some  time now.